# converting a string to a readable sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

say you have a list like so:

```
lst = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'jack.']
```

If I convert to a string doing this:

```
''.join(lst)
```

**output**

```
'mynameisjack.'
```

How do I make the list print out:

```
 "my name is jack."
```

instead of all together.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `''.join(lst)`(an empty string), use `' '.join(lst)`, with a space (see the documentation of join!).